# Include CDN sources in gulp-inject

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-inject

I am trying to get CDN and other HTTP resources into a script that is modified by [gulp-inject](https://github.com/klei/gulp-inject).

I created [a corresponding issue](https://github.com/klei/gulp-inject/issues/18) at the repository.

The gist is that I would like something along these lines to work:

```
var sources = [
  "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine.js",
  "./spec/test.js"
]

gulp.task('source', function () {
   gulp.src("src/my.html")
       .pipe(inject(sources))
       .dest("dest/")
})
```

With that result being the following included in `dest/my.html`:

```
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine.js'>
</script>
<script src='/spec/test.js'></script>
```

Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote a plugin, [`gulp-cdnizer`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-cdnizer), specifically to help with this situation.

It's designed to allow you to keep all your CDN sources local during development, then replace the local path with a CDN path when you build your distribution.

Basically, you install your vendor scripts using bower or just copy-and-paste, and inject them into your HTML using the local path. Then, pipe the results of `gulp-inject` into `gulp-cdnizer`, and it will replace the local paths with the CDN path.

```
gulp.task('source', function () {
   return gulp.src("src/my.html")
       .pipe(inject(sources)) // only local sources
       .pipe(cdnizer([
           {
               package: 'jasmine',
               file: 'bower_components/jasmine/jasmine.js',
               cdn: 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/${version}/jasmine.js'
           }
       ])
       .dest("dest/")
});
```

I like doing it this way a lot better, because you can still develop offline.  The cdnizer library can also handle local fallbacks, which makes sure your page still works if the CDN fails (for whatever reason).

Comment: Thanks @OverZealous. It's definitely along the right lines, though `inject` would be inserting references just to arbitrary placeholder strings, and `gulp-cdnizer` would be converting them to CDN references. It should work though - I'll give it a go, but it might be confusing for the next folks. :)

Comment: Hmm. There are two issues I have encountered. First, it does not work if the files do not exist. Second, this solution will likely not work for a livereload url e.g. `http://localhost:35728/livereload.js` which is a target problem (editing the question to note this now).

Comment: If you aren't using the local features of cdnizer, then you will probably have a much simpler solution using [gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-replace/).

Comment: Yep, I'm thinking `gulp-replace` is going to be the answer, though cdnizer is really cool - thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: I went with `gulp-replace`, but I'm sure anyone encountering the same problem will read the comments and figure it out. :)

Comment: Any chance you could share how you're using gulp-replace. The example provided are pretty vague.

Answer (score 1):

I used `gulp-replace` for a similar use case:

html:

```
<!-- replace:google-places -->
```

gulp:

```
return gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.src, '/*.html'))
    .pipe($.inject(injectStyles, injectOptions))
    .pipe($.inject(injectScripts, injectOptions))
    .pipe($.replace('<!-- replace:google-places -->', replacePlaces))  // <-- gulp-replace
    .pipe(wiredep(_.extend({}, conf.wiredep)))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve')));
```

replacePlaces:

```
const replacePlaces = match => {
    switch (process.env.NODE_ENV){
      case 'dev':
        return '<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js....."></script>';
      case 'production':
        return '<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js......"></script>';
      default:
        return match;
    }
  }
```